# Filtering query results in a datasheet subform causes the "Enter Parameter Value" window to pop up

Tags: ms-access

Sometimes when I use the filter options from the column headers of a query in a subform (datasheet format) the "Enter Parameter Value" window pops up for two fields that are in the linked database that the query is pulling from. These parameters are not even what the query is searching by. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the "compact and repair database" button fixed this problem.